# NEW TITLE -- The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

After making the project simpler, I believe I identified the problem is actually a result the async marshalling.

UPDATE:  I made the code simpler to try to figure out what was going on.  So here is an update... The Observable collection is being populated on a new thread (async method).  I tried moving the assigning of the ItemsSource to after the ObservableCollection is loaded as seen below

```
   async void LoadAllData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender != null)
        {
            App.GeoLocationComplete -= LoadAllData;
        }
await ViewModelObjects.NearbyLocations.LoadLocationData();
lvPlaces.ItemsSource = ViewModelObjects.NearbyLocations.GBSLocationDetails;
}
```

The definition for the data load method is a follows:

```
public async Task LoadLocationData()
    {....}
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

I know what is causing the error (the data was loaded on a thread other than the UI thread) but I don't know how to fix it.  Suggestions?

UPDATE UPDATE:  So I believe I have identified the root cause of the problem but have not figured out how to fix it.  I started by simplifying my code as follows and it worked.

```
    public nearbyplaces()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        LoadAllData(null, null);
    }

    void LoadAllData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lobj_Places = new ObservableCollection<GBSLocationDetail>()
        {
            new GBSLocationDetail()
            {
                Title = "Location 1",
                Distance = "20 Miles",
                AddInfo = "Something Else",
                AttributesTexts="Gay, Bar, Dance"
            }
        };

        lvPlaces.ItemsSource = lobj_Places;

    }
```

HOWEVER, what I need is for the LoadAllData method to be called once I have the GPS location from the device.  So in my App.XAML.cs I have the following delegate event declared:

```
    public static Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator gobj_RealGeoCoordinator;
    public static event GeoLocationCompleteEventHandler GeoLocationComplete;
    public static bool gb_WaitingForLocation = true;
```

Then I have the following code call the event once I get the location back from the device:

```
   private async void ProcessStartupandResume()
    {

        if (gobj_RealGeoCoordinator == null)
        {
            gobj_RealGeoCoordinator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            ViewModelObjects.AppSettings.CanAccessLocation = App.gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.IsGeolocationEnabled;

            if (!ViewModelObjects.AppSettings.CanAccessLocation)
            {
                await MainPage.DisplayAlert(ResourceStrings.GetValue("NoLocationServicesTitle"), ResourceStrings.GetValue("NoLocationServicesMessage"), ResourceStrings.GetValue("OKButtonText"));
            }

            //Only add the events if the object has to be created. 
            gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.PositionChanged += gobj_RealGeoCoordinator_PositionChanged;

            gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.PositionError += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ProcessException(new Exception(e.Error.ToString()));
            };
        }

        //Set this to null to trigger the first check
        ib_GPSReenabled = null;

        if (gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.IsListening)
            await gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.StopListeningAsync();

        gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        await gobj_RealGeoCoordinator.StartListeningAsync(10000, 20);

    }

    private static void gobj_RealGeoCoordinator_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = e.Position;
        ViewModelObjects.AppSettings.Latitude = pos.Latitude;
        ViewModelObjects.AppSettings.Longitude = pos.Longitude;

        if (gb_WaitingForLocation)
        {
            gb_WaitingForLocation = false;
            GeoLocationComplete?.Invoke(new object() , null);
        }
    }
```

Then  in my page I subscribe to the GeoLocationComplete event using the LoadAllData method as seen below.  Even when I use a local object and try to set the ItemsSource for the ListView in the code when executed as a result of the event being raised, I receive the error.  See code below which subscribed to the event:

```
    public nearbyplaces()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        if (App.gb_WaitingForLocation)
            App.GeoLocationComplete += LoadAllData;
        else
            LoadAllData(null, null);
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: when  you load data, are you adding items to an existing instance of ObservableCollection, or creating a new instance?  Also, I would try commenting out the complex nested grid and just putting a single label in your ViewCell with a binding, to simplify debugging this.

Comment: I initialize the collection in the class constructor

    public VM_NearbyLocations()
        {
            this.GBSLocationDetails = new ObservableCollection<GBSLocationDetail>();
        }

Then I Load the collection with items from the results of a WebAPI 

    this.GBSLocationDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<GBSLocationDetail>>(await lobj_PlacesResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

I will try the simplified approach tomorrow and let you know the results.

Comment: You are replacing the collection the list is bound to with a new instance.  That won't (I think) work the way you intend it to.

Comment: Actually I am not - The observable collection is within a static instance of the class that contains it.  Thus the collection only gets created the first time the class is created.  Regardless, the NotifyPropertyChanged event should trigger the UI to update with the new information in the collection to be the best of my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I figured it out.  I needed to invoke the event on the main thread and I did that with the following code:

```
      Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                GeoLocationComplete?.Invoke(new object(), null);
            });
```

After inserting this code, the error was gone.  Changing the code back to simply

```
GeoLocationComplete?.Invoke(new object(), null);
```

cause the error to occur again.  Thus I believe this resolved my problem.  Hope this helps someone else. :)